# How to add attributes and behavior to an already written class

Tags: inheritance, design-patterns

I wonder if there is a good practises to add some attributes and beahaviors to an already written class.
In my example, I've made a basic class User. Now, in an other milestone, I want to add a notification system, and add a NotificationList in the class User (and the associated behaviors).
In my opinion I have 3 choices :

1. Write the new attributes/functions in my class User. But for each new feature, I will have to update a class that is already written, tested, etc. And the class User will be overloaded each time
2. Use the inheritance : a class UserWithNotification that extends User, and make User abstract. But for each new feature in the future, I will have to extends, and extends, and extends...
3. Use the decorator pattern, but in my case I'm not sure it fits

I'm trying to learn how a project can be as flexible as possible, to support new features that arrives late in the developpment. Thank's for help !

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would go with **Option 1**. If I got it right, all you want to do is add a new property to the `User` class, which is a pretty common thing on a living thing as a software application. Even if you have tested your `User` class already, this would be a "simple" addition of a new property, which shouldn't affect that much your already written code. I am not really sure what a `NotificationList` is about, but my guess is that most if not all the associated behaviours can and maybe should be placed in a hypothetical new class `Notification`.

**Option 2** would become a mess with more and more different kinds of `User`s in your codebase. Definitely a no-go.

**Option 3**, as you wrote does not really fit in this use case in my opinion.

Wrapping up, with the context provided by you in the question I would definitely go with Option 1, which is not only the simplest (software, in general, should remain as simple as possible and should only be complexified when there is a really good reason for doing so) but also the one that fits best your use case.